# PAN not works in java sound api

Tags: java, wav, javasound, audio

I have a big problem, I have developed a Java application which aims to test hearing, delivering sounds at different frequencies (500Hz - 6000Hz) and decibels, so good until apareción a problem in some notebooks does not work well because when you run a sound to the right ear is delivered to the two ears, the same with the left. At first I thought it was a mistake on my application, but when I found an example of similar oracle java  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html was the same was taken aback. I can also be hardaware rule because in my notebook windows7/fedora working properly in linux.

I can only begin to see the solution to level drivers or operating system for the application to run on any computer.

-I have tried it on multiple computers, so far has not worked in 2 samsung, 1 HP and 1 Toshiba (new and used, it is not a matter of sound settings)

-This application also works well be me that is C + + http://www.programming.de/freeware_windows.php (ear test)

-Here's a code sample http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_play_wav_sound_file.xml

-I tried creating. Wav files in stereo and mono mode (with Audacity)

-In java I installed the 1.4 jre to test the current

-Probably many of you would work because it depends on the computer

a piece of code:

```
private void propiedadesSound()
{
        this.clipAudio.stop();
        this.clipAudio.close();
        try
        {
            InputStream temp = getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.archivo);
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(temp);
            this.audio = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);
                this.clipAudio.open(this.audio);
                if(this.clipAudio.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.PAN))
                {
                    FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) this.clipAudio.getControl(FloatControl.Type.PAN);
                    if(this.jRadioButtonIzq.isSelected())
                     pan.setValue(-1.0f);
                     else if(this.jRadioButtonDer.isSelected())
                     pan.setValue(1.0f);
                     else if(this.jRadioButtonAmbos.isSelected())
                     pan.setValue(0.0f);
                }
        else if(this.clipAudio.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.BALANCE))
                {
                    FloatControl pan = (FloatControl) this.clipAudio.getControl(FloatControl.Type.BALANCE);
                    if(this.jRadioButtonIzq.isSelected())
                    pan.setValue(-1.0f);
                    else if(this.jRadioButtonDer.isSelected())
                    pan.setValue(1.0f);
                    else if(this.jRadioButtonAmbos.isSelected())
                    pan.setValue(0.0f);
                 }
                if(this.clipAudio.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN))
                {
                    FloatControl gain = (FloatControl) this.clipAudio.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
                    float max = gain.getMaximum();
                    float min = gain.getMinimum();
                    float current = gain.getValue();
                    double gainValue = this.jSliderDecibel.getValue()+20;
                    float newValue = (float)(min + gainValue * (max - min) / 100.0F);
                    gain.setValue(newValue);
                }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex)
        {
            exitError("Archivo de audio no soportado.");
        }
        catch (LineUnavailableException ex)
        {
            exitError("Linea no soportada.");
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            exitError("Error en la lectura del archivo de audio."+ex);
        }
    }
```

pd: I also tried removing the code PAN only, balance and only two like this now

someone comes up with an alternative?, the code must be java as it is part of a larger program, but perhaps you could add some other language dll

Thank you in advance

/-----EDIT--------------------------------/

I found a solution that is not definitive but it has worked so far. The notebooks that had the problem were coming from the factory, for some reason fails to divide java sound so have been formatted, you have installed a new windows (in this case Windows 7), the same version of Windows that was bringing but not factory, after that it worked every notebook I had that problem. Therefore it is an incompatibility of factory drivers of some notebooks with java api, which has not been updated for many years

/----------------------------------------/

Answer (score 2):

The definition of PAN is a bit vague. You may not get complete stereo separation depending on how they interpret PAN.

I recommend opening a stereo line and doing your own panning. I do this in JSyn and I get complete stereo separation.

If you want a tone on only one channel then write the tone to one channel and zeros to the other.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing, with the addendum that extreme values of PAN *should* (but apparently don't) leave you with sound in only one channel or the other. But even if that's the case it may be attenuated by an unknown amount. (Hi phil!)

Comment: Thank you for reply, I created a file (.wav) on Audacity, stereo, with one channel in silence and the other with tone 1000 hz, my problem persist, i can't hear only on right or left